# LiveKit Server SDK: "preset" property not found in "IngressVideoOptions"

Tags: typescript, next.js13, react-typescript, livekit

I'm working with the LiveKit Server SDK and trying to set the video encoding preset for an Ingress. However, I'm encountering the error:

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'preset' does not exist in type 'IngressVideoOptions'.`

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import {
  IngressVideoEncodingPreset,
  // ... other imports
} from "livekit-server-sdk";

// ...

options.video = {
  source: TrackSource.CAMERA,
  preset: IngressVideoEncodingPreset.H264_1080P_30FPS_3_LAYERS,
};
```

I've verified that the `livekit-server-sdk` package is up-to-date and the `IngressVideoEncodingPreset` import seems correct. I have also tried to update my typescript and upated `npm install livekit-server-sdk`, still the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Update:
It is working with the old version but the new version has these error:
on

```
`if (ingressType === IngressInput.WHIP_INPUT) {
    options.bypassTranscoding = true;
  } else {
    options.video = {
      source: TrackSource.CAMERA,
      encodingOptions: {
        value: IngressVideoEncodingPreset.H264_1080P_30FPS_3_LAYERS,
        case: "preset",
      },
    }
  }`
```

error: Type

`'{ source: TrackSource; encodingOptions: { value: IngressVideoEncodingPreset.H264_1080P_30FPS_3_LAYERS; case: "preset"; }; }'`

is missing the following properties from type 'IngressVideoOptions': name, equals, clone, fromBinary, and 7 more.

I have tried to add `name` and it does work, but the other properties seem to be non existing in dependency.

Documentation: https://docs.livekit.io/server-sdk-js/classes/IngressVideoOptions.html

Comment: Here is doc: https://docs.livekit.io/egress-ingress/ingress/overview/#Using-video-presets

Answer (score 1):

The docs showed an outdated version for livekit-server-sdk 1.x.

The latest major version is 2.x and constructing those options has changed a bit:

```
const ingress: CreateIngressOptions = {
  name: 'my-ingress',
  roomName: 'my-room',
  participantIdentity: 'my-participant',
  participantName: 'My Participant',
  video: new IngressVideoOptions({
    source: TrackSource.SCREEN_SHARE,
    encodingOptions: {
      case: 'preset',
      value: IngressVideoEncodingPreset.H264_1080P_30FPS_3_LAYERS,
    },
  }),

  audio: new IngressAudioOptions({
    source: TrackSource.MICROPHONE,
    encodingOptions: {
      case: 'preset',
      value: IngressAudioEncodingPreset.OPUS_STEREO_96KBPS
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response, i really appreciate it. I tried to do this but then it gave another error, related to encodingOptions, mentioning to add all of the properties of ingressVideoOptions

Comment: @Mannu sorry about the errors. There was a naming conflict in the SDK, which has since been fixed. The `TrackSource` enum will work as intended now!
Wanted to keep the `TrackSource.SCREEN_SHARE` in the answer as its intent is a lot clearer than a plain number

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question.

Here's what worked for me:

I downgraded my dependencies for
`"livekit-client": "^1.15.4",` &
`"livekit-server-sdk": "^1.2.7",`. Additionally, I imported `livekit-server-sdk/dist` after the downgrade.

This approach has effectively resolved the error. I will now attempt to update to the latest versions to see if that resolves the issue permanently. Please give me a few minutes to try this out.